# MySQL sum values from same day

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, sum

I have a table which looks like this:

```
visitor_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
log_time DATETIME
```

As you can tell, it logs how many visitors there where in certain time periods. Now I want to show these values in a graph. I need to be able to "zoom out" meaning that I want to sum up all the `visitor_count`s whos log_time belongs to the same day, week, month. Is anything like this possible in SQL/MySQL with the aid of PHP (I'd prefer doing it in SQL since I believe it is much more efficient than getting all the values and summing them up in PHP)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could extract just the date part and sum according to it:

```
SELECT   DATE(log_time), SUM(visitor_count)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY DATE(log_time)
```